# WPF hot keys similar to xamribbon alt keys

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, infragistics, wpf-4.0

Hi I am having a wpf application. I need to show some hot keys to user when they press alt key. The hotkeys must be displayed untill any keydown or click happens. this is similar to `XamRibbon alt key` I guess this is the same functionality in Excel using alt key.

I could implement by using `InputBindings and KeyDown and KeyUp events` but my business need is to let it display till user clicks somewhere else or some selection happens or some typing happens. which is the same in XamRibbon and Excel.

How do we achieve this kind of behavior??

Comment: you can open pop up when hitting alt and then display them until click is being done

Comment: so... why not use a XamRibbon?

Comment: I have to show hot keys on some controls not just ribbon